# matching ending CSS curly brace when it ends without a semicolon

Tags: css, regex

How to match the ending CSS curly brace `}` that doesn't have semicolon in front of it? See examples in the following cases:

This should be matched:

```
.style { margin: 0px; width: 10px }
.style {
   margin: 0px;
   width: 10px
}
```

But not in this:

```
.style { margin: 0px; width: 10px; }
.style { margin: 0px; width: 10px;}
.style {
   margin: 0px;
   width: 10px;
}
```

I'm trying to use this, but looks like there are some issues with using negative match:

```
string.match(/[^;](!?\s+)?(})/mg)
```

Comment: ewwwww weeeee... I hope you aren't using regex for parsing.

Comment: no, just for appending the !important attribute

Comment: hmm, I don't see the need for the negative lookahead.  Are you just interested in matching ONLY `}` which doesn't have a semicolon in front of it?  `[^;\s](?:\s*)?(})` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming JavaScript. This adds the missing semicolons:

```
s.replace(/([^{};\s])(\s*})/g, "$1;$2")
```

I include `{}` in the first character class, since there could be empty rules:

```
.foo {}
```

The pattern captures the last non-whitespace character before the brace, since JavaScript does not support look-behinds. Since I was already capturing characters, I captured the closing brace as well, instead of using a look-ahead.